# Having the extra same layout across all devices. How?

Tags: android, layout, adt, device

I want to make a game with exact the same Layout across all devices. I'm familiar with `dp`, `wrap_content` and `fill_parent`. But they don't produce the EXACT same Layout.

Is there a way to make the width and height of various views, as well as their mangins from the edges of the device screen, in percentages relative to the screen width and height?

Something like:

```
android:layout_width="40%"
```

I know the above XML code doesn't work, but is there a workaround? Isn't there a in-Java solution to this? Something?
In the image below is what I'm trying to achive to happen in all devices.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know the above XML code doesn't work, but is there a workaround?

`LinearLayout` and `android:layout_weight` allow you to work on a percentage basis. The following layout has three buttons, given 50%, 30%, and 20% of the screen respectively:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="@string/fifty_percent"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:text="@string/thirty_percent"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:text="@string/twenty_percent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

To do things on a percentage basis, set the width or height (for horizontal or vertical `LinearLayouts`, respectively) to be `0dp`, then assign `android:layout_weight` to the desired percentage (e.g., `20`). If the sum of the weights will not add to 100, add `android:weightSum="100"` to the `LinearLayout` itself.

Of course, doing things on a percentage basis will not give you "the EXACT same Layout" for any conventional definition of the term "EXACT". But, perhaps it will meet your needs. It certainly can implement the marked-up design from your screenshot.

Comment: The problem with LinearLayout is that it doesn't allow to put views on top of each other.In my image the background is a movie that plays in a ViedeoView. Is it posible to nest a LinearLayout inside a RealativeLayout, for the same activity?

Comment: @user2186852: "Is it posible to nest a LinearLayout inside a RealativeLayout, for the same activity?" -- sure.

Comment: @user2186852: Note that layering things on top of a `VideoView` may cut playback performance, particularly on older devices.